# Custom EditItem Page

Tags: list, custom-list, custom-form, list-form, custom-actions

Is there a way to create a custom edit item page for SharePoint list items using HTML/CSS/JS? I want to be able to modify EditItem.aspx so that I could add divide the fields into different sections and insert buttons on the page. I've tried to using [Mark Rackley's solution](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/) for this task but I am unable to pre-populate the fields in my HTML page with existing data.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
Does it have to be entirely in SharePoint?  Why not build the page out using exactly the things that you know, HTML/CSS/JS and make all of your connections to a SharePoint list?

Option 2:
Edit the form in SharePoint designer.